# How to enable cache server JNDI lookup support in Coherence 12.2.1?

Tags: oracle, caching, jndi, lookup, weblogic12c

I am trying to access Coherence 12.2.1's cache (deployed in data tier) from application tier (deployed in application tier) that staying same Coherence cluster with different WebLogic clusters.

Oracle stated:

```
A component-scoped JNDI tree can be used in EJBs, servlets, or JSPs to reference the NamedCache.

To use a component-scoped JNDI lookup, define a resource-ref of type com.tangosol.net.NamedCache in either the web.xml or ejb-jar.xml file. Example 3-2 illustrates a <resource-ref> stanza that identifies myCache as the NamedCache.
```

in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24442/coh_wls.htm#COHWL117

I developed a Coherence application and deploy it into local storage enabled WebLogic server (coherence managed server). I used Application Lifecycle Listener to access and initialise cache, it works fine.

I can find the cache was populate up in Coherence cache server by using VisualVM, please see attachment.[image]

But unfortunately, I can't find any thing about the cache in my WebLogic managed server JNDI tree, Please find attachment.[image]

I tried to find out a way to enable Coherence cache server (it was integrated into WebLogic 12c) support JNDI look up.

I found something like this:

```
<cache-config xmlns:jndi="class://com.oracle.coherence.environment.extensible.namespaces.JNDINamespaceContentHandler">

   ...

</cache-config>
```

But unfortunately again, com.oracle.coherence.environment.extensible.namespaces.JNDINamespaceContentHandler was removed from WebLogic 12c. Which means there is no way to enable Coherence data cache JNDI name configuration in Coherence 12cR2.

Any advice please!!

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to create the ConnectionFactory, Outbound pools, etc ?

I suggest you take a look at this post [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/reynolds/entry/coherence_adapter_configuration). It should help you out.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: I will try your suggested to see what's going on next step. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: How to access cache config file that was wrapped in a .gar file and deployed into a app server?

Comment: the .gar file is probably deployed together with the application. It's inside the .ear or .war file deployed on $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/<MANAGED_SERVER>/tmp/_WL_user/<Application_name>/<RANDOM_NUMBER>/ 

Once you're there, start looking for the gar file. Usually people place it on the root directory of the package or inside WEB-INF.

Grab it, open it and then you'll have the config file you need.